# jquery select h1 from loaded remote page in $(data)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to select a h1 from a remote page that I've loaded into $(data).
No matter how I've tried I just cant seem to get the code right.
If I use this code:

```
console.log($(data));
```

I get:

```
[text, meta, text, meta, text, script, text, title, style, text, style, text, h1, text, h2, text, br, text, br, text, table, text, hr, init: function, selector: "", jquery: "1.4.2", size: function, toArray: function…]
```

And at the index 12 is what I want to fetch. But how?
I thought this would work, but it returns nothing:

```
console.log($(data).find('h1').text());
```

If I remove text() I get:

```
[prevObject: c.fn.c.init[23], context: undefined, selector: "h1", init: function, jquery: "1.4.2"…]
context: undefined
length: 0
prevObject: c.fn.c.init[23]
0: text
1: meta
2: text
3: meta
4: text
5: script
6: text
7: title
8: style
9: text
10: style
11: text
12: h1
13: text
14: h2
15: text
16: br
17: text
18: br
19: text
20: table
21: text
22: hr
length: 23
__proto__: Object[0]
selector: "h1"
__proto__: Object[0]
```

And there it is again, at index 12. What is it that I've missed/don't understand?

Best Regards
Niclas

Comment: Could you show your code and data in a jsFiddle?

Comment: Does `.filter('h1').text()` work?

Comment: .filter('h1') worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Find will [*Get the **descendants** of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.*](http://api.jquery.com/find/) Take the following example.

```
$('<p></p><a>One</a>').find('a').text(); 
Outputs: ""
$('<p><a>Two</a></p><a>One</a>').find('a').text();
Outputs: "Two"
```

Notice that `<a>Two</a>` is a descendant of `<p>` here. I think what you need is filter.  *[Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)*

```
$('<p></p><a>One</a>').filter('a').text(); 
Outputs: "One"
```

Comment: That makes sense now :)